# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in NGINX with Subdomain

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have the following NGINX Config (Server 1) and /private is a wordpress install:

```
location /private/ {
  include cloudflare;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin private.domainofserver2.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_pass http://private.domainofserver2.com/;
}
```

When I access https://domainofserver1.com/private I get the following error in my console

`Access to Font at 'https://private.domainofserver2.com/wp-content/themes/entrada/vendors/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0' from origin 'https://private.domainofserver1.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'https://domainofserver`.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

My Wordpress (Server 2) Config is:

```
# Allow access from all domains for webfonts.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

How can I resolve my error as the above does not work